# In LISP, what's the difference between "let" and "with"?

Tags: lisp, substitution, let

A simple example to show the differences in action would really help, since to me they both just seem interchangeable? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp, at least, you can only use `with` in the context of a `loop` macro.  See the [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_aaea.htm).

Comment: But are "let" and "with" both functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed functionally equivalent.

In fact, at least SBCL expands any use of `with` in a `loop` macro invocation into an enclosing `LET` form.

Running the following:

```
(macroexpand '(loop with foo = 5 repeat 10 collect foo))
```

Results in the following expansion:

```
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((FOO 5))
    (LET ((#:LOOP-REPEAT-1681 (CEILING 10)))
      (DECLARE (TYPE INTEGER #:LOOP-REPEAT-1681))
      (SB-LOOP::WITH-LOOP-LIST-COLLECTION-HEAD (#:LOOP-LIST-HEAD-1682
                                                #:LOOP-LIST-TAIL-1683)
        (SB-LOOP::LOOP-BODY NIL
                            ((IF (<= #:LOOP-REPEAT-1681 0)
                                 (GO SB-LOOP::END-LOOP)
                                 (DECF #:LOOP-REPEAT-1681)))
                            ((SB-LOOP::LOOP-COLLECT-RPLACD
                              (#:LOOP-LIST-HEAD-1682 #:LOOP-LIST-TAIL-1683)
                              (LIST FOO)))
                            ((IF (<= #:LOOP-REPEAT-1681 0)
                                 (GO SB-LOOP::END-LOOP)
                                 (DECF #:LOOP-REPEAT-1681)))
                            ((RETURN-FROM NIL
                               (SB-LOOP::LOOP-COLLECT-ANSWER
                                #:LOOP-LIST-HEAD-1682))))))))
```